# Mover tarjetas entre divs con javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo identificar que tarjeta esta en que `div` pueden ejecutar el codigo para ver mi resultado. Necesito que al mover una tarjeta me identifique en que `div` se encuentra ya sea en el primero o el segundo.

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".task");

for(let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcId", ev.target.id);
  });
}

dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let target = ev.target;
  let droppable  = target.classList.contains('box');
  let srcId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcId");
  
  if (droppable) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcId));
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 90vh;
}

.task {
  background-color: pink;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">
            <div id="task1" class="task" draggable="true">
                arrastrame
            </div>
            <div id="task2" class="task" draggable="true">
                arrastrame
            </div>
            <div id="task3" class="task" draggable="true">
                arrastrame
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo probablmente sea asignar un identificador a cada uno de lox boxes, y mediante [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) obtener su id.

El `.task` concreto que estás moviendo puedes obtenerlo también del evento.

```js
var dropTarget = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".task");

for(let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
  draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("srcId", ev.target.id);
     console.log(ev.target.parentNode.id)
     console.log(ev.target.id)
  });
}

dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let target = ev.target;
  let droppable  = target.classList.contains('box');
  let srcId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("srcId");
  
  if (droppable) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(srcId));
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 90vh;
}

.task {
  background-color: pink;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="org-box" class="box">
                <div id="task1" class="task" draggable="true">
                    arrastrame
                 </div>
                 <div id="task2" class="task" draggable="true">
                     arrastrame
                 </div>
                 <div id="task3" class="task" draggable="true">
                     arrastrame
                 </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="target-box" class="box">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otra opción sería que en lugar de poner un listener a cada `.task` se lo pusieras únicamente a los `.box`. De este modo `evt.target` sería el elemento del dom sobre el que se inicia el evento y `evt.currentTarget` sería el elemento `.box` al que añadiste el listener.

Comment: En la consola me muestra a que div fue pero no que tarjeta es la que se ha movido, me ayudas con eso?

Comment: Cambiado. Por tu pregunta entendía que querías saber cual era el `.box` no el `.task`. Recuerda marcar la pregunta como aceptada si tu duda está resuelta.

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (ordenes:299)_

Comment: El código que te posteo no da ese error. Supongo que habrás cambiado algo, si no tiene relación con esta pregunta abre otra. Si lo tiene actualiza la pregunta